# javascript function only returns undefined

Tags: javascript

The following javascript function only returns undefined

```
function digital_root(n) {
  var x = String(n).split('');
  if (x.length > 1) {
    sum = x.reduce((accumulator, value) => parseInt(value) + accumulator, 0);
    digital_root(sum);
  } else {
    console.log(x);
    return x;
  }
}
```

however it prints the correct value when run in node. So why does it return undefined?

```
> digital_root(12)
[ '3' ]
undefined
```

If I take the `console.log(x)` statement out, the function still returns undefined

```
> digital_root(12)
undefined
```

Comment: wheres the return statement in the if true branch?

Comment: @MarianTheisen You were correct, that was the issue. I didn't realize I needed a return statement there as well.

Answer (score 1):

The first time your function runs it goes into the `if` block, where it calls itself again with argument `digital_root(3)`.

This "inner" call is processed first now, this time going into the `else` block, where the `console.log(x)` call happens and then `return ['3']` explicitly returns that value **to the outer function call**, so that return value is not shown on the console.

After the inner call returned the value, the outer function terminates, because there's nothing left to do, so the outer function never returns anything.

Functions do have a **default** return value of `undefined` whenever there is not explicit `return` statement.

Comment: If I take the `console.log(x)` statement out, the function still only returns undefined. However, I know that `x` should be returned since it was able to printed. Or am I misunderstanding something fundamental?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to include `return` for the recursive call.

The full code should look like this

```
function digital_root(n) {
  var x = String(n).split('');
  if (x.length > 1) {
    sum = x.reduce((accumulator, value) => parseInt(value) + accumulator, 0);
    return digital_root(sum);
  } else {
    console.log(x);
    return x;
  }
}
```